# How to score mean absolute error using cross_val_score and KFold from sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, scoring

I'm wondering how to compute the `mean_absolute_error` using `cross_val_score` of `sklearn`:

I have `X,y` and I'm writing

```
cross_val_score(X,y, cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True))
```

Maybe I should try to split the data and instantiating a `for` loop.. something like

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold as kf

for i in kf.split(X,y):

...

?
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `scoring` parameter like this:

```py
scores = cross_val_score(X,y, cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True), scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')

print('Mean score over all folds: ', scores.mean())
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but that's what I getback: ValueError: scoring value <function mean_absolute_error at 0x000001DAD0F33DC0> looks like it is a metric function rather than a scorer. A scorer should require an estimator as its first parameter. Please use `make_scorer` to convert a metric to a scorer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please see edit above. That is one way to make the metric a scorer. Did that help?

Comment: But how can I retrieve the mean absolute error then?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The `cross_val_score` function returns the scores for each fold. You can then get the mean score and standard deviation if needed from that. See the documentation for more details: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to my own question as I think that I have found another way in order to obtain the `mean_absolute_error` straight. Hope to receive some feedback on this.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
xgb = XGBoostRegressor()
scores = []

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
    xgb.fit(X.iloc[train_index].values, y.iloc[train_index].values)
    preds = xgb.predict(X.iloc[test_index].values)
    mean_abs = mean_absolute_error(y.iloc[test_index].values, preds)
    scores.append(mean_abs)
```